# Physical significance of an equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Can anyone explain to me what the physical significance of the following equation is?

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol v=\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol a.
$$

where $\boldsymbol r$ is coordinate vector, $\boldsymbol v$ is velocity vector and $\boldsymbol a$ is acceleration vector. What is the significance of the result?

Comment: Where did you get the equation from? What is the context?

Answer (score 2):

The equation gives the relationship between angular acceleration $\mbox{d}{\boldsymbol \omega}/\mbox{d}t=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(\boldsymbol r\times\boldsymbol v)$ for given linear acceleration $\mathbf a$. It's a kinematic equation, so in a sense there's really no physics in there.

Comment: Why is there no physics? It's certainly more than mathematics.  And why assume a linear acceleration?

Comment: No, it's nothing more than mathematics. Geometry in space-time, if you will, but without the physical content of relativity theory, mind you.

Comment: Assignment of concepts of velocity, acceleration, linear motion, angular motion are definitely physics.

Comment: I *think* I disagree, but I'll give you that this would make for an interesting discussion. However,  I don't think this is the appropriate place to have said discussion. Also note that I was not trying to imply that the question is off-topic.

Comment: But, briefly, if you look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematics), you can see that it claims that "*Kinematics is [a] branch of classical mechanics...*", so that's a point for you, but then goes on to say that "*Kinematics as a field of study is often referred to as the "geometry of motion" and as such may be seen as a branch of mathematics*". I'd call that a tie. This is coming from someone with joint appointments in physics and applied mathematics, by the way ;-)

Comment: So you agree there IS physics present. It's not exclusively mathematics. :)

Comment: I'm torn, really: "Two souls alas! are dwelling in my breast", as famous German poet Goethe said...

Comment: r does not need to be a constant,  the term with the derivative of r always vanishes because dr/dt and p are parallel

Comment: Oops, you're right, I fixed my post.

Comment: "*It's a kinematic equation, so in a sense there's really no physics in there.*" Why this sentence? Is kinematics suddenly not physics? Angular velocity and angular acceleration are very much physical properties, and this expression is how they are tied together.

Comment: @Steeven We went over this already, see comments #4 and 5.

Comment: Aha. Mixing math with physics doesn't make it pure math. That makes no sense. Anyways, I don't see the need of this confusing sentence in the otherwise good answer, therefore the reaction.

Comment: @Steeven I think I can make an argument that goes a lot deeper than this, but like I said, this is not the place for such a discussion. In any case, notice the qualifier "*in a sense*" in the pertinent sentence of mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply both sides by the mass, $m$, you get
$$\dfrac{d\left(\vec{r}\times\vec{p}\right)}{dt}=\vec{r}\times\vec{F}.$$

The cross product on the left is the angular momentum of the particle of mass $m$ about some point from which you are measuring $\vec{r}$. The cross product on the right is the torque on that particle due to some force. This new equation says that a torque will change the angular momentum of the particle.

Comment: Well, now you have definitely brought physics into the picture. ;-)